# jquery on click add css value in percentage

Tags: jquery, onclick, percentage

I'd like to add 100% incrementally to margin left on click.

So say my current margin value is 100%
Then On click = 200%
On second click = 300%
and so on...

How do I do this? I searched all over, can't find a solution. It's easy to add 100 pixels but i need percentage value.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For browser consistency, I would suggest you to use this kind of snippet:

**EDITED FOLLOWING COMMENT**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxjWf/)

```
$('.slide-back').data('marginLeft',10).on('click',function(){
    var $inner = $('.inner'), curMarg = $(this).data('marginLeft') + 10;
    $inner.css({marginLeft:curMarg+'%'});
    $(this).data('marginLeft',curMarg);
});
```

Comment: thx @Ramaraj Karuppusamy for fixed typo

Comment: Thanks! This works however I have a div with class 'inner' and the button with class 'slide-back'. So when the button is clicked I don't want to add the margin to the button, instead I want to add the margin to div 'inner'. The following doesn't seem to work `$('.slide-back').data('marginLeft',10).on('click',function(){
     var $this = $(this), curMarg = $this.data('marginLeft') + 10;
     $this.css({marginLeft:curMarg+'%'}).data('marginLeft',curMarg);
  });`

Comment: How many elements with class .inner? If just one, the fix is simple to find... BTW, reading your question, im sorry, i cannot divine it!

Comment: there is just one element with class .inner

Comment: Reupdated answer, should work now. If yes, please upvote and accept answer

Comment: So, is it working or still not?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! And since you were confused about what I was trying to do, I'm creating a slider. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/beliy333/aH466/1/

Comment: Oh and instead of adding adding 10 to 10 like in your code, how do I add 10 to the current margin-left value? So if the current margin value was 25 then the result would be 35.

Comment: I ran into a problem, I need to make two controlling divs. One is 'slide-back' which adds 100% to current margin and the other is 'slide-forward' which will subtract 100% from current margin. How would I go about this?

Comment: I apologize if I came off expecting to much. I'm new to this forum and new to jQuery. Thanks for your time, I really do appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you doing such thing. (margin in percentage). 
But here it is:
**[Check Out LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/t8Usz/1/)**

**jQuery**

```
$('.mydiv').click(function()
{
    var currentMargin = parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'));
    $(this).css('margin-left',currentMargin+100+'%');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='mydiv'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mydiv
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question too but, if you try to get the margin doubled, in PX , %, or whatever, you can do it that way (based on roasted fiddle) :

```
$('b').click(function(){
  var curMargStr = $(this).css('marginLeft');
  var curMarg = curMargStr.replace('px','') * 2;
  $(this).css('marginLeft', curMarg);
});
```

You can't get the value in percent, as the browser has to translate in px to render it.
Note the value can change depending on the browser you're using.

Comment: @roasted 's code works however I have a div with class 'inner' and the button with class 'slide-back'. So when the button is clicked I want to add the margin to div 'inner' not the button 'slide-back'. The following doesn't seem to work `$('.slide-back').data('marginLeft',10).on('click',function(){
     var $this = $(this), curMarg = $this.data('marginLeft') + 10;
     $this.css({marginLeft:curMarg+'%'}).data('marginLeft',curMarg);
  });` Why % you ask? It's for wordpress plugin I'm creating. It finds imgs in your post and puts them in a responsive slider. I'll share the code once it works.