# add percentage value instead of px

Tags: jquery, css

i want to create (some kind of) a fullwidth slider, where i have a flex-wrapper with several child sections. each seaction is 100vw arranged in a row. now i want to move the flex-wrapper with margin-left 100% everytime you click on a button. it should not add it one time, it should stack up like 100%, click, 200%, click, 300% and so on...

i came up with the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.section-wrapper').css('margin-left', '+=100%');
    });
});
```

it doesnt seem to work. when i replace 100% with 1920px it works as intended. (on my fullhd monitor)

any ideas?

EDIT:
heres my codepen, i hope its getting clearer now:
https://codepen.io/tuxedo/pen/gOazMxv

Comment: `.css('margin-left', '100%');`

Comment: did you try removing '+=' ?

Comment: @freedomn-m _"...with margin-left 100% **everytime you click on a button**"_

Comment: yes, but it should not add it one time, it should stack up everytime you click on it. like margin-left: 100%; CLICK; margin-left: 200%; CLICK; margin-left: 300% and so on...

Comment: You could give this a try: [jquery on click add css value in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870861/jquery-on-click-add-css-value-in-percentage)

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this's what you're looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var e = document.getElementsByClassName("section-wrapper");
        var marLeft = getStyle(e, 'margin-left');
        var final_width = marLeft + 100;
            final_width = final_width+"%";
        $('.section-wrapper').css('margin-left',final_width);
    });
});
```

or another way:

```
var width_value = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        width_value += 100;
        $('.section-wrapper').css('margin-left',width_value+"%");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You said that each section is already at full viewport width. So I assume you want to do the addition for the sliding animation. What about adding the full width this way?

*Edited according to your CodePen*:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.section-wrapper').css('margin-left', 
            `+=-${document.body.clientWidth}px`);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your input, the appreciated answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Somethings you need to know

- id should be unique .. don't use same id for more than one element (`id="section"`) should be `class="section otherClasses"`
- When you work with `display : flex;` use `min-width , max-width , min-height , max-height`
- use [`flex-direction: column;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- No need to use `justify or align or flex` for the wrapper it will make the wrapper stick on the middle section

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slide_number = 1;
  $('.button').click(function() {
    var sections_num = $('.section-wrapper > .section').length; // get number of sections inside the wrapper
    $('.section-wrapper > .section:eq(0)').animate({'margin-left' :  -slide_number * 100+'vw'} , 1000);
    slide_number = slide_number == sections_num - 1 ? 0 : slide_number + 1; // increase slide_number by 1 if the slide_number is less then the sections_num if there are the same return to the first section
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222222;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-flow: row nowrap;*/
  width : 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  max-width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction : column;
  -webkit-flex-direction : column;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width : 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  max-width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.section-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width : 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  max-width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh
}

/* .section-wrapper.scroll {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
} */

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: cadetblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bisque {
  background: bisque;
}

.aliceblue {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.aquamarine {
  background: aquamarine;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, aquamarine 0%, aliceblue 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="section aquamarine">
      <div class="button">
        <p>button 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section aliceblue">
      <div class="button">
        <p>button 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section bisque">
      <div class="button">
        <p>button 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>The main idea in my code `$('.section-wrapper > .section:eq(0)')` I used the **first section** to do the move **not** the **wrapper**</sup>

- If you don't need the `animate` effect you can easily change `1000` with `0` in  `.animate({'margin-left' :  -slide_number * 100+'vw'} , 1000);`